# Unable to add ICS Calendar Invites to iOS Calendar

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app, calendar, ical

### Problem

Calendar invites sent to my email (usually .ics attachments, as they originate from a customers' Exchange server) do not add and sync to my calendar. The UI to handle the calendar invite differs from my wife's phone (as evidenced in the screenshots below. Invites work as expected on her phone, but not on mine. This happens to be the case on all of my iOS devices (iPad, iPhone 11 Pro and iPhone 7).

### My devices (all iOS 14.0.1)

iPad 6th Generation, iPhone 11 Pro, iPhone 7 (no SIM)

### My wife's devices (iOS 14.0.1)

iPhone 11

### Services (all inclusive and simplified, for troubleshooting)

- iCloud Mail and Calendar DISABLED on both of our accounts
- Google account connected, syncing Mail, Contacts and Calendars
- Default Mail and Calendar on all accounts are not Gmail and Google Calendar

### Detail (My devices)

When I receive a meeting invitation, there is an .ics attachment. When tapping on that attachment, I am presented with a card that has "Add to calendar" and "Delete Event" at the bottom.

- My name appears in the invitee list with a gray "?"
- Tapping on "Add to Calendar" brings up another card where I can choose the calendar to add the event to (in this case, I choose Personal Calendar, but it doesn't matter what calendar I choose, the results are the same).
- I then tap "Done" in upper right corner
- Card disappears
- Event never shows up on calendar, and never syncs back to the cloud (Google, in this case, but could be iCloud, Outlook.com or Exchange)

### Screenshot

[image: My screenshot (not working)]

### Detail (Wife's device)

When she receives a meeting invitation (from same source), the same .ics attachment appears. When tapping on that attachment, she is presented with a card that has "Accept", "Maybe", and "Decline" at the bottom.

- Her name appears in the invite list with a green "checkmark"
- Tapping "Accept" immediately adds the event to her calendar (visible in iOS Calendar app as well as web version of Google Calendar

### Screenshot

[image: Wife's screenshot... working as expected]

### Troubleshooting

- Performed a full factory reset and set up device AS NEW (not restored)
- Deleted and re-added iOS Mail application
- Installed Gmail application from App Store (to determine if that application provided different sync functionality to default iOS apps)
- Installed Outlook app from App Store (Outlook RSVP also didn't work on any calendar)
- INTERESTING NOTE: If Siri detects an event in the email message and I tap on the small bar at the top that says "Siri found 1 event", it WILL add to my calendar.

I am at a loss as to what could be different on my device or account that is preventing my Mail and Calendar from behaving as they should, and it is creating issue with meeting invites accepted while traveling. I have to actually accept on a laptop OR hope Siri finds an event and tap that to add it to the calendar.

Any help you all could provide would be appreciated!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

On your iphone in Settings > Mail > Account, you have to enable Calendar on the Mail account on which the meeting invitation with the ics files is received.